# Execute ColdFusion Tags

Tags: coldfusion

I am at learning stage in ColdFusion. Now I am trying to execute below code to display variable content by using `<cfset>` and `<cfoutput>` tags. I completed my server installation and I am able to login to server with admin credentials. But it executed as normal html page, not getting the result from ColdFusion tags.

Do I need to install anything apart from this?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
body>
<body background="download.jpg">
<cfset name ="swanav"/>
<cfoutput>#name#</cfoutput>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please clarify how you are trying to run this code.  The term, `execute below code to display variable content by using enter code here, tag`, doesn't make any sense.

Comment: did you save this page as `.cfm` page?

Comment: Hi Bracuk,
   I have saved above code with the name sample.cfm and placed in wwwroot folder. Opened browser and gave complete path in task bar ex.C:\ColdFusion2016\wwwroot\sample.cfc. As per tag  "<cfoutput>#name#</cfoutput>" tag , the content of the variable "name" should be present in output. But I am getting result is #name#, I assuming the content of the variable is not presenting it just giving as html result. Could you please help me on it what I need to do exactly.
Thanks,

Comment: Make sure your web server is set to host .cfm pages through the ColdFusion server. Might need to rerun the connector setup.

Comment: Yes I have saved above code with .cfm.

Comment: Thank you Shawn for you reply..as per document which I have read. they mentioned no need worry about web server. I am kindly request you to ask,can you tell me how I can set up web server to host.

Comment: A couple more comments. Your example code is missing the opening bracket `<` on the `body` tag. That may throw the browser off. You mentioned saving the file as `sample.cfm` but said that you requested `sample.cfc`. That is not a `cfc` file. You should be requesting the `.cfm` file in your broweser. You also mentioned that you requested `C:\ColdFusion2016\wwwroot\sample.cfc`. Aside from the wrong extension as I already mentioned, you should be requesting the file from a URL, not physical path. Something like `http:\\localhost\sample.cfm` or `http:\\your.domain.com\sample.cfm`.

Comment: Thank you Miguel. I will try as you said.

Comment: You may want to try using http://127.0.0.1:8500/sample.cfm as your address.  If you have the server setup to use the local builtin cold fusion web server, the above link will work.

Answer (score 0):

A small correction to your code,

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body background="download.jpg">
  <cfset name="swanav" />
  <cfoutput>#name#</cfoutput>
</body>

</html>
```

The code needs to be placed in,
/cfusion/wwwroot